# Configuration file is not found for bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind

I'm running bitcoind in ubuntu. When I pass password as argument, it shows no configuration file found. Somebody please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see it here,

> cd  $HOME/.bitcoin/

Comment: That's correct, however it's important to know that the configuration file is not created by default, so it is not particularly astonishing if you don't find it.

Comment: yeah, that's true